# Firing CellEditingTemplateSelector of DataGridTemplateColumn on custom events

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

Instead of double click or F2 to go to edit mode in DataGrid I want to do this on some button click event, Is there some override mechanism available for overriding default behavior. I am using DataTemplateColumn. Snippet is below:

```
var column = new CustomColumn()
                {
                    Width = 100,
                    Header = String.Format("#{0}", j + 1),
                    CellTemplateSelector = this.FindResource("CustomColumnTemplateSelector") as DataTemplateSelector,
                    CellEditingTemplateSelector = this.FindResource("CustomEditTemplateSelector") as DataTemplateSelector
                };
```

I need to call CellEdittingTemplate on my own custom events instead of by default double clicking event.
Any ideas please!

Comment: Catch double clicks events and do nothing with them before they reach DataGrid for example in Grid if DataGrid is inside a Grid or in StackPanel. Just set e.Handled = true and the double click event wont reach to DataGrid. If you want to start edit a cell get the desired DataGridCell instance and call BeginEdit() method.